# PostgreSQL > ERROR: not all tokens processed SQL state: 42601

Tags: postgresql

Hi All PostgreSql expert,

I am trying to insert data using (insert into table select * from table) statement. Like
Insert into table_a select * from table_b;

But it gives me "ERROR:  not all tokens processed, SQL state: 42601".
Not able to find a solution.
Any input will help here.

Comment: Look into the PostgreSQL log file for the message, [edit] the question and copy and paste the complete log entry.

Comment: Check/Post your table DDL. Your statement "Insert into table_a select * from table_b;" requires both tables to have exactly the same number of columns and each column type in table_a correspond to the same column type in each position for columns in table_b.